# Programming API for `redis-cli info commandstats`

Tags: api, redis

I want to collect the output of `redis-cli info commandstats`. I went through top programming languages, the all contain the call `redis-cli info` but not the `redis-cli info commandstats`. Any solution to get the output for `redis-cli info commandstats` via programming language?

Comment: Actually libredis (go) will provide you with the data directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using python (2.7.6), the redis module (2.10.5, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis) and the short script below (which expects that you have a redis-server on localhost:6379):

```
import redis

for key, value in redis.StrictRedis().info('commandstats').iteritems():
    print key, value
```

I can see the 'commandstats' information just fine (truncated below):

```
cmdstat_zrange {'usec_per_call': 17.92, 'usec': 233, 'calls': 13}
cmdstat_spop {'usec_per_call': 2.33, 'usec': 14, 'calls': 6}
cmdstat_hincrby {'usec_per_call': 6.4, 'usec': 64, 'calls': 10}
cmdstat_srem {'usec_per_call': 2.77, 'usec': 2459, 'calls': 887}
cmdstat_zrangebyscore {'usec_per_call': 6.46, 'usec': 2303850, 'calls': 356382}
...
```